# Obtener datos con pandas desde un csv

Tags: python, pandas

espero que esten muy bien, quiero saber como hacer para que en base a la busqueda de un dato me entregue el 'Numero' y el 'Nombre' de la fila donde se encuentra el valor obtenido.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("covid.csv", index_col="Numero")
contagios = df["contagiosTotales"]
contagios_maximos = contagios.max()
print(contagios_maximos)
```

Este es el archivo python

```
Numero,Nombre,contagiosTotales,contagiosDiarios,contagiosActivos,muertesTotales,muertesDiarias,vacunasAplicadas,vacunasSinAplicar,vacunasTotales
p1,a,1234,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
p2,b,12345,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
```

Y este ultimo es el archivo csv.
Mi duda es la siguiente:
El programa en ptyhon logra calcular correctamente que 12345 es el valor maximo de la columna 'contagioTotales', para que esto sea mas visual necesito que me imprima el 'p2' y el 'b'.
Ahora bien, necesito que esto sea dinamico porque en un futuro voy a tener que agregar nuevas provincias (cuando hablo de provincias es a p1 o p2 en este ejemplo).

Es posible que tenga que usar el indice de la fila?Como haria en ese caso?

Comment: se me acaba de ocurrir una solucion, puedes seleccionar desda la columna 1 hasta la 3 y luego aplicar la funcion `max()` con la tercera columna (contagios totales) y luego te muestre esos 3 datos (numero,nombre contagiosTotales), creo que existe una mekjor forma, pero por ahora es mi solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario, una solucion seria coger las 3 primeras columnas y usar la funcion `max()` en ellas, voy a proporcionar 2 ejemplos para solucionar tu problema

##### Primera forma

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("covid.csv", index_col="Numero")

#podemos convertirlo a DataFrame si queremos
# df = pd.DataFrame(df)
contagios = df[:len(df)][:3] #escogemos lo que nos interesa

#obtenemos el maximo de contagios
resultado = contagios.max()

#imprimimos los datos (nombre,contagiosTotales,contagiosDiarios,etc)
print(" ".join(f"{res}" for res in resultado))

#accedemos a la columna de "contagiosTotales"
print(resultado.contagiosTotales)
```

Bueno lo que hicimos aquí fue escoger los datos `df[:len(df)][:3]`, luego hayamos el máximo, lo que nos devolverá la fila entera y por eso podemos acceder a sus columnas, para ver los datos hacemos uso de una compresión de lista pero metida en un `print()` finalmente accedemos a la columna que nos interesa `resultado.contagiosTotales` que es lo mismo que hacer `resultado["contagiosTotales"]`

**Salida**

```
b 12345 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
12345
```

##### Segunda forma

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("covid.csv", index_col="Numero")

#asignamos un nuevo nombre para que sea mas intuitivo
contagios = df

#filtramos los datos
#esto nos dará la fila que coincida con el valor máximo de la columna "contagiosTotales"
result = contagios[contagios.contagiosTotales == contagios.contagiosTotales.max()]

#mostramos los resultados
print(result)
```

Esta forma es mas facil, pues solo filtramos los datos que coincidan con el valor maximo obtenido de la columna "contagiosTotales" de esta forma `contagios.contagiosTotales.max()` que es lo mismo que `contagios["contagiosTotales"].max()`

**Salida**

```
       Nombre  contagiosTotales  contagiosDiarios  contagiosActivos  muertesTotales  muertesDiarias  vacunasAplicadas  vacunasSinAplicar  vacunasTotales    
Numero
p2          b             12345                12                12              12              12                12                 12              12
```

Comment: Gracias Christian me re sirvio y funcionaa!!! Siempre me salvas alto capo

Comment: De nada :) recuerda aceptar la respuesta si soluciono tu problema, eso indicara que la respuesta fue buna y ayudara a otras personas con problemas similares

Comment: Listo capo!!sos el mejor!